# How to use conditional formatting to highlight an entire row of column of data in googlesheets based on specfic date in that row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have been struggling with this now for 2 days. I am very hopeful that you will be able to help.

I have a spreadsheet (example provided below) where I need to highlight an entire row using conditional formatting if any of the cells in that row have a date within the specified range.

```
     A             B              C              D              E 
                Place 1        Place 2        Place 3        Place 4
    
3    Item A     26.10.2021                                   10.8.2021
4    Item B                    15.10.2021
5    Item C                                   20.9.2021
6    Item D
7    Item E     1.10.2021
```

So, for example, I would need to highlight the entirety of row 3 when I am looking for a date within the last week. Or the entirety of row 5 if I was looking for something with a date last month.

So far I have tried using the Today() function to specify my ranges, such as today()-1 for the last 24 hours, today()-7 for the last week etc. I have looked at videos from Prolific Oaktree trying to understand CF better, I have tried every combination I can think of with things like ISBETWEEN.

The spreadsheet I am working with has several hundred columns and thousands of lines, so this isnt something where I can go through and write a formula for each individual row.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CF rule based on a formula:

[image]

It highliths all rows if any date in the row's cells contains a date between start and end dates (at right side)

My formula is:

```
=COUNTIFS($B2:$E2;">="&$H$2;$B2:$E2;"<="&$H$3)>0
```

If I change start and end date, CF rule will update instantly:

[image]

Comment: It just highlights everything. Every row, even rows that have no date in them at all.

Comment: How did you set the conditional formatting rule? @DajanRa

Comment: =COUNTIFS($D7:$HD1000;">="&$A$9;$D7:$HD1000;"<="&$A$8)>0

to correspond to where things are in my sheet

Comment: A8 is 26.10.2021 and A9 is 10.10.2021

Comment: You did wrong. notice my formula use only 1 relative row. And then, because of relative references, it works. If your data is in range `D7:HD1000`, select that range and then apply CF rule with `=COUNTIFS($D7:$HD7;">="&$A$9;$D7:$HD7;"<="&$A$8)>0 `